# Detect red color in different illumination or background

Tags: opencv, colors, computer-vision

I can't find the best way to detect red color in different illumination or background.

I found that there's [YCbCr color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) which is good for red or blue color detection (actually I need to detect blue color too). The problem is that I can't figure out which threshold to use in different lightning. For example in sunny weather this threshold equals 210 (from 255), when in cloudly weather this threshold equals 130.

I use OpenCV library to implement this.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is usually used for such purpose. In HSV you can tell that whatever is brightness etc, red is what is needed. I also recommend to look into two places. One is simple tutorial http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/ and another is to take a book [Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)  and use examples of histograms from there. They do exactly what you need. Using HSV and Histograms makes your solution solid.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I didn't know that HSV is better than YCbCr for red color detection.

Comment: Hey Tõnu! Thanks again for your reply. I've tried HSV color space - it's better than YCbCr, but the problem is that I still haven't find a good solution of my problem. In your answer you mentioned histograms. Unfortunately I don't have sample codes from that book, but I looked in default OpenCV samples. Actually I know what is histogram. But I don't understand how can it help me to detect red color. I will calculate HSV histogram of the image - and what's next? Thanks.

Comment: Google my friend! http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596516130/ and http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/ may be for help.

Answer (score 1):

HSV color space should be more robust to change of illumination.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't help me in any illumination. Maybe other advice? Thanks.