# Detect only red pixels in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, rgb

I need to detect all the red pixels in an image using Java. What 's the best way to do this?

Only supposing a pixel is red when the Red RGB-value is > 200 isn't good enough (see [this table](http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm)).

So is there a better way to do this? Or is there some red-color-rgb algorithm?

Comment: You're asking two questions here: One is, *"How do I determine if some colour (denoted by RGB values) looks red?"*, and the other, *"Can you write this program for me in Java?"*. The first question is fine, the second one isn't (thus my downvote)... unless you demonstrate that you've already made some effort of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [YCrCb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space.

Simple algorithm: convert your RGB image to YCrCb, extract red channel and make a threshold.

Comment: Can you please provide some code / pseudo-code examples of red color extracting and applying a threshold?

Answer (score 3):

Convert RGB to [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and threshold the hue (H) component.

Comment: Hue value is red when > 345 or < 15? so: `if (hsv[0]*360 > 345 || hsv[0]*360 < 15) {` But that doesn't give an acceptable result...

Comment: @francisMi: Please be more specific.  What is not acceptable?

Comment: @francisMi have you tried my solution? Also take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/flowdesigner/index.php?title=OpenCV) article. They also detect red color using HSV (and RGB).

Comment: @Astor: But what about it is unacceptable?  I can't help if the OP doesn't give any details.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It doesn't detect all red colors (maybe because of different illumination). See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992479/detect-red-color-in-different-illumination-or-background). I still haven't found good solution.

Comment: @Astor: I guess it depends on your definition of "red"!  If you can define which colour coordinates equate to red, then you can define a threshold for it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, you're right. But the problem is that I don't want to do 10 thresholds because I use it in video and everything has to do really fast.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, you probably want to do some comparison in HSB space.  You'll probably want to define an appropriate rage for all three values based on what your expectations are.

You can use `Color.RGBtoHSB` to get the values from a given color.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB%28int%2C%20int%2C%20int%2C%20float%5B%5D%29

Comment: 1.4.2?  Please feel free to join us in the ***3rd*** millennium!  Where currently looking at Java 7.

Comment: If you do a google search for `Color.RGBtoHSB`, the 1.4.2 documentation is the first link. I've found that to be the case with most Java searches that I do - the old documentation comes up first. I have to append '7' to each search to get it so bring up the latest docs, which is quite a shame.

Comment: With some URLs (including this one) you can just replace "1.4.2" in the path with "7".